# Highcharts equivalent of this Raphael.js chart demo -- possible?

Tags: javascript, raphael, highcharts

Is it possible to do the equivalent of [this Raphael.js chart demo](http://raphaeljs.com/chart.html) in Highcharts? Namely, to be able to have the graph animate a transform into the new data.

The only example I've seen of charting new data in Highcharts simply redraws the entire chart, instead of transforming the points into the new data. So I'm not sure it's even doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many examples on the Highcharts web site, but yes lately highcharts have implemented the animate option which is on by defualt, so that when you change data, the graphs animate into the new positions.

One example I have found is this: [Highcharts animation example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jaRhY/)

```
chart: {
    animation: {
        duration: 1000
    }
},
```

Of course you can find more information on Highcharts Options Reference (look for chart options and then animation).

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew there were lots of demos - I looked at most of the ones on their site. I didn't see this one anywhere. Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to look at alternative libraries like [**Elycharts**](http://elycharts.com), a MIT licensed, SVG+VML charting library supporting "step animations", look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JehdF/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,see
http://captico.com/animation-with-raphaeljs/2010/07
There is more links and examples @
http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/raphaelsource.php

Comment: Thanks but I want to know how to do something like that Raphael demo in *Highcharts* - I'm not asking how to do it in Raphael.